# In Javascript, what does the function* notation mean?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Reading documentation for https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga and they have a notation on function i am not familiar with:

```
// worker Saga: will be fired on USER_FETCH_REQUESTED actions
function* fetchUser(action) {
   try {
      const user = yield call(Api.fetchUser, action.payload.userId);
      yield put({type: "USER_FETCH_SUCCEEDED", user: user});
   } catch (e) {
      yield put({type: "USER_FETCH_FAILED", message: e.message});
   }
}
```

what does the **function*** mean?

Comment: yeah, hard to search for that because of the `*` - see - [function* docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*)

Comment: In case of redux-saga, generator functions is used for support potential infinite event loop of asynchronous methods. Generally, generators delegate async/wait infrastructure to caller. See https://github.com/tj/co for classic implementation